# How to make an object move with conditions

Tags: java

so I am trying to make lorries move towards an entity (site) only if it meets certain criteria (using "ifs").

So the plan is that I have 2 lorries (created inside an array in case I want to add more in the future and for easier manipulation in the script), and they are originally placed at a concrete plant in the center. The user makes a site appears on the screen when he clicks (other sites are added at every click).

There are three criteria in order to choose which truck to move to the site when a site is created:

- If the truck is available (not in delivery, delivery = deliv);
- If the truck as enough cement (each lorry start with 2 units (u), and every time it goes to a site, it looses 1 unit. When it reaches 0 it needs to go back to the concrete plant to "fill up")
- The truck that is the nearest (by checking the distance);

I have created a series of loops to check these conditions in the draw function. Starting by saying that if the lorries are available, then check if it has units of cement. If no then destinations are changed to concreteplant, if yes then calculate the distance between the lorry and the site.

The I have another loop that will allow to select the lorry with the smallest distance (smallD).

Another loop to say to take that lorry with the smallest distance and assign the destination as site and go to the next site etc + setting delivery to true as it is become unavailable (so it doesnt change direction while it is going to the first site when a new site is clicked).

The I have created a final loop to say to update the lorry which means to move it, display it and checked progress (functions in the lorry class).

This is my script:

```js
/*preload = "factory_12.png";*/
/*preload = "sign.png";*/
/*preload = "simple_truck.png";*/

ArrayList<Lorry> lorries; 
ArrayList<Site> sites;

PImage concretePlant;
PFont aFont;
int xCoord;
int yCoord;
int siteSize = 30;
int siteNumber = 0;

void setup() // What is called once at the beginning
{
  size (500, 500);

  concretePlant = loadImage("factory_12.png");
  aFont = createFont("IndustrialRevolution-Regular", 12);
  textFont(aFont);

  xCoord = int(width/2);
  yCoord = int(height/2);

  //Creating empty Array List where store sites objects
  sites = new ArrayList<Site>();

  //Adding first site
  sites.add(new Site(random(width), random(height), siteSize));

  //storing lorries
  lorries = new ArrayList<Lorry>();
  lorries.add(new Lorry(xCoord, yCoord));
  lorries.add(new Lorry(xCoord, yCoord));
}

void draw() // Draw the background and concrete plant
{
  background (235, 247, 255);
  image(concretePlant, xCoord, yCoord, 60, 60);
  fill(1);
  text("Concrete Plant", xCoord-20, yCoord+70);

  //Calling the sites
  for (int i = sites.size () - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    Site site = sites.get(i);
    site.displaySites();
  }

  float[] distanceCheck = new float[lorries.size()];

  for (int i = 0; i< lorries.size (); i++) {
    if (lorries.get(i).deliv == false) {
      println ("delivery check");
      if (lorries.get(i).u > 0) {
        PVector siteTemp = new PVector (sites.get(siteNumber).x, sites.get(siteNumber).y);
        PVector lorryTemp = new PVector (lorries.get(i).location.x, lorries.get(i).location.y);
        distanceCheck[i] = PVector.dist(siteTemp, lorryTemp);
        println ("distanceChecked");
      } else {
        lorries.get(i).destination.x = xCoord;
        lorries.get(i).destination.y = yCoord;
        println("goingBack");
      }
      println("first for done");
    }
  }

  int smallestD = -1; 

  for (int i = 0; i <lorries.size (); i++) {
    if ((distanceCheck[i] > 0) && (distanceCheck[i] == min(distanceCheck))) {
      smallestD = i;
    }
    println("smallest found");
  }
  if (smallestD >= 0) {
    lorries.get(smallestD).destination.x = sites.get(siteNumber).x;
    lorries.get(smallestD).destination.y = sites.get(siteNumber).y;
    if (siteNumber < sites.size() -1) {
      siteNumber++; // siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
    }
    lorries.get(smallestD).deliv = true;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < lorries.size (); i++) {
    lorries.get(i).updateLorry();
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  sites.add(new Site(mouseX, mouseY, siteSize));
}

class Lorry
{
  PVector location;
  PVector concretePlant;
  PVector velocity;
  float d; //distance
  int u; //unit of cement
  boolean r; //Reserved lorry
  boolean deliv; //
  PImage mixer;
  boolean changeDirection;

  PVector destination;

  Lorry(float xCoord, float yCoord)
  {
    concretePlant = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    location = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord, 0); //Initial start point
    velocity = new PVector(2, 2);
    u = 2;
    r = false;
    deliv = false;
    mixer = loadImage("simple_truck.png");
    //destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
    destination = concretePlant;
    //PVector temp = new PVector (destination.x, destination.y);
    changeDirection = false;
    //d = PVector.dist(location, temp);
  }

  void displayLorry()
  {
    image(mixer, location.x, location.y, 30, 30);
  }

  void move()
  {
    float xdir = destination.x - location.x;
    float ydir = destination.y - location.y;
    PVector dir = new PVector (xdir, ydir);
    dir.normalize();
    location.add(dir);
    print("going");  
    //deliv = true;
  }

  void checkProgress()
  {
    if (dist(destination.x, destination.y, location.x, location.y) < 1) {
      deliv = false;
      //u --;
      //      if (siteNumber <sites.size() -1) {
      //        siteNumber++; // siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
      //      }
    }
  }

  void updateLorry()
  {
    displayLorry();
    move();
    checkProgress();
  }
}

class Site

{
  float x,y;
  float size;
  PImage picture;

  Site (float xin, float yin, float sin)
  {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    size = sin;
    picture = loadImage("sign.png");
  }

  void displaySites()
  {
    image(picture, x, y, 60, 60);
  }
}
```

> **Site**

[image: Site]

> **Lorry**

[image: Lorry]

> **Concrete Plant**

[image: Concrete Plant]

Comment: Are you sure this code compiles? I can't compile it. You commented `boolean changeDirection` in Lorry but still use it. This does not compile for me neither `float d = new PVector.dist(location, destination);`

Comment: How can I change it do it compiles? I have just copied my code from my screen and added it on here :/ Also you're right I have added back in the change Direction and instead of having float d in a function I have just moved it up un Lorry as I realised that it may not need its own function.

Comment: Ok so I have updated it. But I still dont know how to change it so it compiles. Maybe its because of the images in there and it needs access? Now when I run the code it tells me "Cannot find a class or type names "PVector.dist" for my d in the Lorry class.

Comment: Have you actually stepped through your code with a debugger? Have you verified if the problem is just in the display of the lorries or the internal data?

Answer (score -2):

I made a few modifications:

- first it was not compiling
- then I added a few utilities on the `Lorry` class which simplifies the code in the `draw` method
- And finally, I tweaked the algorithm in the `draw` method to pick the correct Lorry

I think the following code works as expected.

You still need to make a Site for the plant, this way you can set it as destination for a Lorry when it needs to reload. Then when it reaches the plant, you set the units back to 2, and it should keep going to the next site after that. Good luck!

```
/*preload = "factory_12.png";*/
/*preload = "sign.png";*/
/*preload = "simple_truck.png";*/

ArrayList<Lorry> lorries; 
ArrayList<Site> sites;

PImage concretePlant;
PFont aFont;
int xCoord;
int yCoord;
int siteSize = 30;
int siteNumber = 0; // keeps track of the index of the nest site to deliver to

void setup() // What is called once at the beginning
{
  size (500, 500);

  concretePlant = loadImage("factory_12.png");
  aFont = createFont("IndustrialRevolution-Regular", 12);
  textFont(aFont);

  xCoord = int(width/2);
  yCoord = int(height/2);

  //Creating empty Array List where store sites objects
  sites = new ArrayList<Site>();

  //Adding first site
  sites.add(new Site(random(width), random(height), siteSize));

  //storing lorries
  lorries = new ArrayList<Lorry>();
  lorries.add(new Lorry("Lorry 1", xCoord, yCoord));
  lorries.add(new Lorry("Lorry 2", xCoord, yCoord));
}

void mousePressed() {
  sites.add(new Site(mouseX, mouseY, siteSize));
}

// This returns the next site to deliver to
// Returns null if no more sites
Site getNextSite() {
  Site site = null;
  if(siteNumber < sites.size()) {
      site = sites.get(siteNumber);
  }
  return site;
}

void draw() {

  // Draw the background and concrete plant
  background (235, 247, 255);
  image(concretePlant, xCoord, yCoord, 60, 60);
  fill(1);
  text("Concrete Plant", xCoord-20, yCoord+70);

  // Displaying the sites
  for (int i = sites.size () - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    sites.get(i).display();
  }

  // Ckeck if there is a next site to deliver to
  Site nextSite = getNextSite();

  if(nextSite!=null) {
    // If yes, find out which lorry should go
    Lorry lorryToGo = null;

    // List all available lorries (not delivering or out of units)
    ArrayList<Lorry> availableLorries = new ArrayList();
    for(Lorry l : lorries) {
      if(l.isAvailableForDelivery()) {
        availableLorries.add(l);
      }
    }    
    // if any, find the closest
    if(!availableLorries.isEmpty()) {
      lorryToGo = availableLorries.get(0);
      for(Lorry l : availableLorries) {
        if(l.checkDistanceToSite(nextSite) < lorryToGo.checkDistanceToSite(nextSite)) {
          lorryToGo = l;
        }
      }
    }


    // If a lorry has to go, set its new destination
    // and increase the siteNumber 
    if(lorryToGo != null) {
      println(lorryToGo.name + " to go");
      lorryToGo.destination = nextSite;
      lorryToGo.delivering = true;
      siteNumber++;
    }
  }

  // update all lorries
  for(Lorry l : lorries) {
    l.updateLorry();
  }

}


class Lorry {
  String name;
  PVector location;
  PVector concretePlant;
  PVector velocity;
  int units; //unit of cement
  boolean reserved; //Reserved lorry
  boolean delivering; //
  PImage mixer;
  boolean changeDirection;
  Site destination;

  Lorry(String name, float xCoord, float yCoord) {
    this.name = name;
    concretePlant = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    location = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    velocity = new PVector(2, 2);
    units = 2;
    reserved = false;
    delivering = false;
    mixer = loadImage("simple_truck.png");
    destination = getNextSite();
    changeDirection = false;
  }

  boolean isAvailableForDelivery() {
    return !delivering && units > 0;
  }

  boolean needsToReload() {
    return units <= 0;
  }

  void displayLorry() {
    image(mixer, location.x, location.y, 30, 30);
  }

  float checkDistanceToSite(Site site) {
    return PVector.dist(location, new PVector(site.x, site.y));
  }

  void move() {
    float xdir = destination.x - location.x;
    float ydir = destination.y - location.y;
    PVector dir = new PVector (xdir, ydir);
    dir.normalize();
    location.add(dir);
  }

  void checkProgress() {
    if (destination != null && checkDistanceToSite(destination) < 1) {
      println(name + " reached destination");
      delivering = false;
      units--;
      if(needsToReload()) {
        println(name + " needs to reload");
        destination = null;
        // put some code here to send the truck back to the plant
        //destination = plant
      } else {
        destination = getNextSite();
        println("assigning new destination with index: "+siteNumber);
        println("assigning new destination: "+destination);
      }
    }
  }

  void updateLorry() {
    if(delivering)
      move();

    displayLorry();
    checkProgress();
  }
}

class Site {
  float x,y;
  float size;
  PImage picture;

  Site (float xin, float yin, float sin) {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    size = sin;
    picture = loadImage("sign.png");
  }

  void display() {
    image(picture, x, y, 60, 60);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have made some progress and changes again... Sorry about that. I am re-editing the script I have posted and tell you what has changed and what my problem is now.

Comment: @Lilly I updated my answer to use a list of lorries, have a look. It seems to work fine.

Comment: @Lilly [You should instead ask a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188627/379373).